# Generalization of Helly theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, infinitary-combinatorics

I am working on Helly theorems But it is a very famous theorem which has many many different types; Here is a well-known and basic version of Helly:

> [image]
>   "Lectures on discrete geometry Jiri Matousek"

**Does anyone knows a generalization which in works on another spaces ???
I mean a version that not be only for $\mathbb{R}^{d}$**